# Declare children components in wrapper for jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I have a component "Tabs" that I used like that :

```
<template>
    <Tabs>
      <Tab title="Title 1">Content test 1</Tab>
      <Tab title="Title 2">Content test 2</Tab>
      <Tab title="Title 3">Content test 3</Tab>
    </Tabs>
</template>
```

I use `this.$children` to retrieve all Tab in my Tabs component.

How can I mock this in my unit test to have children in Tabs component ?

I want this :

```
describe('Tabs', () => {    
    it('should display tabs', async() => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(Tabs, {})

        console.log(wrapper.vm.$children.length) // ==> Return Tab count

        expect(true).toEqual(true)
    })
})
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

**EDIT**
Tabs component :

```
<template>
  <section>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :key="tab.title" v-on:click="selectTab(index)">
        <button
          :class="{ 'active': index === selectedIndex }"
          type="button"
        >
          {{ tab.title }}
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import Tab from './tab.vue'

@Component
export default class Tabs extends Vue {
  @Prop({ required: false, type: Number, default: 0 }) private activeTab: number

  private selectedIndex: number
  private tabs: Tab[] = []

  mounted(): void {
    this.selectTab(this.activeTab)
  }
  created(): void {
    this.tabs = this.$children as Tab[]
  }

  selectTab(i: number): void {
    this.selectedIndex = i

    // loop over all the tabs
    this.tabs.forEach((tab, index) => {
      tab.isActive = index === i
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide the code of your ```Tabs``` component?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to find all `Tab` components instead of using `$children` property in test.

```
describe('Tabs', () => {    
  it('should display tabs', async() => {
     const wrapper = shallowMount(Tabs, {})
     expect(wrapper.findAllComponents(Tab)).toHaveLength(YOUR_EXPECTED_LENGTH)
  })
})
```

And I also recommend you to reconsider `Tabs`'s component structure: you better render each `Tab` using v-for inside `Tabs`. It will be much easier to manipulate each `Tab`.

And there is another good solution for creating tabs in Vue - to use [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

Comment: `console.log(wrapper.findAllComponents(Tab).length)` return 0

Comment: Were ```Tab``` components rendered at all? You can check it by calling in ```console.log(wrapper.html())```.